# Wait when all API calls finished in each For loop in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I have a method named `Swap()`, executed for all of the selected records in the `ag-grid`. I am using a for loop to call the `Swap` method for all of them.

I want to wait about 3 seconds at the end of each loop. The code I have is like the following :

```
async SwapOrder(selectedRow) {
    await this.service.getOrder().subscribe(res=>{ //API call
        this.service.Action1().subscribe(res=>{ //API call
         this.service.DeleteApi(res=>{ //API call
          this.service.SwapOrder().subscribe(res={ //API call
            if(res.status==1)
               alert('success');
               });
              });
             });
           });
}
```

And the for loop is like the one below :

```
onSwap(){
     for (const selectedRow of selRows) {
         _this.SwapOrder(selectedRow);
          setTimeout(function () {
          }, 3000);
        }
}
```

I have seen the similar questions on `SO` and I changed the onSwap and `for loop` like below, but still the problem exists and there is no `delay` at the end of each loop.

```
 async onSwap(event, context) {
     var _this = this;
     for await (const selectedRow of selRows) {

     await  _this.SwapOrder(selectedRow);
     setTimeout(function () {}, 3000);
        }
```

*Added `await` inside for loop.* After the last API call in each loop and the first API call in the next loop, must be a delay of about 3 seconds.

Comment: Use obsewrvable operators instead of nesting subscribes. If you need to wait for all observables to emit, i'd start by looking at `forkjoin`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had to return an `Observable` object from `SwapOrder` function, so that can be resolved from the `onSwap` function by using `lastValueFrom` operator.

```
SwapOrder(selectedRow) {
    return forkJoin(
      this.service.getOrder(),
      this.service.Action1(),
    ).pipe(
      switchMap(([order, action1]) => this.service.DeleteApi()),
      switchMap((delete) => this.service.SwapOrder())
    );
}

async onSwap(event, context) {
  var _this = this;
  for (const selectedRow of selRows) {
     const swapOrder = await lastValueFrom(_this.SwapOrder(selectedRow));
     // if you need manual wait you can use below
     // await lastValueFrom(timer(3000));
     if (swapOrder.status === 1) {
       alert("success");
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: I am using `subscribe` because in for example `DeleteAPI` I need a data that I have gotten  in previous API (`Action1`), in this way, how can I use returned data of the previous API call?

Comment: @osmanRahimi please check updated answer

Comment: How can I add a delay at the end of each loop? I mean after each item that proceeded, I want to wait about 3 seconds, then continue the loop.

Comment: @osmanRahimi you can use `await lastValueFrom(timer(3000));` after `SwapOrder`  function is executed

Comment: the version of `Rxjs` I am using is `6.6`, and there is now `LastValueFrom`. is there any equivalence for this?

Comment: Try `await timer(3000).toPromise()`

Comment: Thank You,  is it possible if one API returns false, then  stop others from executing? for example, if the first API call returns data, I want to stop other API call if `response.data.state==0`

Comment: @osmanRahimi yes, that's possible to do. Just one suggestion, It you're fine, feel free to open a new question, that way more people can be involved in the discussion and you can get more ideas about approaches. Thanks :) Glad to know my answer helped you in someway.